# How to initialize a struct value fields using reflection?

Tags: reflection, go

I got a `.ini` configuration file that I want to use to initialize a `Configuration` struct.

I'd like to use the `Configuration` fields names and loop over them to populate my new instance with the corresponding value in the .ini file.

I thought the best way to achieve this might be reflection API (maybe I'm totally wrong, tell me...)

My problem here is that I cannot figure out how to access field's name (if it is at least possible)

Here is my code:

```
package test
import(
     "reflect"
     "gopkg.in/ini.v1"
 )

type Config struct {
    certPath string
    keyPath  string
    caPath   string
}

func InitConfig(iniConf *ini.File) *Config{
    config:=new(Config)
    var valuePtr reflect.Value = reflect.ValueOf(config)
    var value reflect.Value = valuePtr.Elem()
    for i := 0; i < value.NumField(); i++ {
        field := value.Field(i)
        if field.Type() == reflect.TypeOf("") {
            //here is my problem, I can't get the field name, this method does not exist... :'(
            value:=cfg.GetSection("section").GetKey(field.GetName())
            field.SetString(value)
        }
    }
    return config
}
```

Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [type](https://godoc.org/reflect#Value.Type) to [get a StructField](https://godoc.org/reflect#Type.Field). The StructField has the [name](https://godoc.org/reflect#StructField.Name):

```
 name := value.Type().Field(i).Name
```

Note that the ini package's [File.MapTo](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/ini.v1#File.MapTo) and [Section.MapTo](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/ini.v1#Section.MapTo) methods implement this functionality.

Comment: hmmm... I think I get it, thank you. Another last question, is there another way to achieve this without reflection api ?

Comment: You can use the ini package's MapTo functionality (see methods on [File](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/ini.v1#File.MapTo) and [Section](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/ini.v1#Section.MapTo)), but that uses reflect under the hood.

Comment: Oh... Indeed, I didn't see that method. Thanks for the tips.

Answer (score 1):

While @MuffinTop solved your immediate issue, I'd say you may be solving a wrong problem.  I personally know of at least two packages, [`github.com/Thomasdezeeuw/ini`](https://godoc.org/github.com/Thomasdezeeuw/ini) and [`gopkg.in/gcfg.v1`](https://godoc.org/gopkg.in/gcfg.v1), which are able to parse INI-style files (of the various level of "INI-ness", FWIW) and automatically populate your `struct`-typed values using reflection, so for you it merely amounts to properly setting tags on the fields of your struct (if needed at all).

I used both of these packages in production so am able to immediately recommend them.  You might find more packages dedicated to parsing INI files [on `godoc.org`](https://godoc.org/?q=ini).

Comment: actualy @MuffinTop pointed this out in the comments. I was pretty sure it existed such implementations, but as a real Go-newbie, I was more curious about the underlying bare-metal way as it's a common process to assing values to dynamic Object/Struct properties.
Anyway, I agree with you, it's much cleaner using libraries's built-in mapping functionality. Thanks for taking the time to answer.

Comment: @n00dl3, oh silly me: I got so fixated on your direct usage of reflection I did not spot you were already using `gopkg.in/ini.v1` to parse your INI data! So yeah, the @MuffinTop's answer plus their comment is a spot-on.

Comment: JFTR: the `gopkg.in/ini.v1` package wasn't among those I recommended because in my personal opinion that package is a prime example of typical overengeneering with its built-in locking for serializing R/W access being a clear Go anti-pattern. It's okay for a start though so don't bother with this for now, @n00dl3, so long it works ;-)